# How can I fix the 'no data to display' error when trying to load drill down charts with FusionCharts linked charts?

Tags: fusioncharts

I am trying to use fusion Chart links (Linked Charts) for loading drill down chart when you click on a parent chart and it says 'no data to display when I click on parent chart.

Appreciate your help!

### Here is my sample code.

```
FusionCharts.ready(function() {
  var revenueChart = new FusionCharts({
    type: 'stackedcolumn2d',
    renderAt: 'chart-container',
    width: '700',
    height: '400',
    dataFormat: 'json',
    dataSource: {
      "chart": {
        "theme": "fusion",
        "caption": "Revenue split by product category",
        "subCaption": "For current year",
        "xAxisname": "Quarter",
        "yAxisName": "Revenues (In USD)",
        //Showing the Cumulative Sum of stacked data
        "showSum": "1",
        "numberPrefix": "$",
        "theme": "fusion"
      },
      "categories": [{
        "category": [{
            "label": "Q1"
          }         
          
        ]
      }],       
      "dataset": [{
          "seriesname": "Food Products",
          "data": [{
              "value": "11000",
               "link": "newchart-json-test",
               
            }      
          ],
            
           
        },
        {
          "seriesname": "Non-Food Products",
          "data": [{
              "value": "11400",             
            }                       
          ]
        }
      ],
       "linkeddata": [{
                    "id": "test",
                    "linkedchart": {
                        "chart": {
                            "caption": "Fodd Products - Quarterly Sales",
                            "subcaption": "Last year",
                            "numberprefix": "$",
                            "theme": "fusion",
                            "rotateValues": "0",
                            "plottooltext": "$label, $dataValue,  $percentValue"
                        },
                        "data": [{
                            "label": "Q1",
                            "value": "157000"
                        }, {
                            "label": "Q2",
                            "value": "172000"
                        }, {
                            "label": "Q3",
                            "value": "206000"
                        }, {
                            "label": "Q4",
                            "value": "275000"
                        }]
                    }
                }],
   
      
    }
  }).render();
});
```

When you click on the parent chart, it should load a child chart.

Answer (score 0):

For this case, you will have to use configureLink(), because in your case parent chart has multi-series chart data and child is having single-series data, so with the help of configureLink() you can achieve your case.

For reference updated the code as per requirement, please check and hope it will work for you

```
    FusionCharts.ready(function() {
  var revenueChart = new FusionCharts({
    type: 'stackedcolumn2d',
    renderAt: 'chart-container',
    width: '700',
    height: '400',
    dataFormat: 'json',
    dataSource: {
      "chart": {
        "theme": "fusion",
        "caption": "Revenue split by product category",
        "subCaption": "For current year",
        "xAxisname": "Quarter",
        "yAxisName": "Revenues (In USD)",
        //Showing the Cumulative Sum of stacked data
        "showSum": "1",
        "numberPrefix": "$",
        "theme":"fusion"
      },
      "categories": [{
        "category": [{
            "label": "Q1"
          }

        ]
      }],
      "dataset": [{
          "seriesname": "Food Products",
          "data": [{
            "value": "11000",
            "link": "newchart-json-test"
          }],

        },
        {
          "seriesname": "Non-Food Products",
          "data": [{
            "value": "11400",
          }]
        }
      ],
      "linkeddata": [{
        "id": "test",
        "linkedchart": {
          "chart": {
            "caption": "Fodd Products - Quarterly Sales",
            "subcaption": "Last year",
            "numberprefix": "$",
            "theme": "fusion",
            "rotateValues": "0",
            "plottooltext": "$label, $dataValue,  $percentValue"
          },
          "data": [{
            "label": "Q1",
            "value": "157000"
          }, {
            "label": "Q2",
            "value": "172000"
          }, {
            "label": "Q3",
            "value": "206000"
          }, {
            "label": "Q4",
            "value": "275000"
          }]
        }
      }],
    }
      
  });
  
  revenueChart.configureLink([
                { type: 'bar2d' }
            ]);
            
     revenueChart.render();
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/taz05v83/2/)